# Passing function to a react class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this here is a function that I am passing to a react class using context api 
it is supposed to return some values.
this works as its supposed to work when `Mobilebar` is a stateless component
but when I change `Mobilebar` to a class this doesn't work.
`console.log(this.props)` returns `{addFilter: ƒ, removeFilter: ƒ, getOptions: undefined}`

```js
<MyContext.Provider value={{
    getOptions: this.getOptions(),
    getItem: this.state.items,
    options: this.state.options,
    removeFilter: this.removeFilter.bind(this),
    addFilter: this.addFilter.bind(this)
}}>
    {this.props.children}
</MyContext.Provider>

 <MyContextConsumer>
        {({ getOptions, addFilter, removeFilter }) =>                 
            <Mobilebar
            addFilter={addFilter}
            removeFilter={removeFilter}
            getOptions={getOptions} />
        }
 </MyContextConsumer>
```

This is the function

```js
getOptions() {
  if ((this.state.catList &&
      this.state.brandList &&
      this.state.colorList) &&
    (this.state.catList.length != 0 &&
      this.state.brandList.length != 0 &&
      this.state.colorList.length != 0)) {
    return [
      [this.state.brandList],
      [this.state.catList],
      [this.state.colorList]
    ]
  }
}
```

The component

```js
export class Mobilebar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.options = this.props.getOptions;
     
        this.brand = [];
        this.category = [];
        this.color = [];
        this.i = 0;
        this.options ?
        (
        this.brand = this.options[0][0], 
        this.category =his.options[1][0], 
        this.color = this.options[2][0]
        ) : this.i = 1;
    }
    render() {
      
        return (
            <div className="itemlist" >
                <div >
                   <p>T_T_T_T</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong.please guide me( this works fine when `Mobilebar` is a stateless component) 
Is there a problem with the way I am implementing this function in a class??
Why does `console.log(this.props.getOptions)` return `undefined`!!!!!
Thanks for your time !!

As you guys pointed out I tried binding it like this

```
 getOptions: this.getOptions.bind(this)
```

calling it in the `Mobilebar` in this manner

```
 this.options = this.props.getOptions();
```

but `console.log(this.props.options)` is still `undefined`

Comment: you are not binding your getOptions: this.getOptions(), function like other functions, I think it should be getOptions: this.getOptions.bind(this)

Comment: You're calling it and passing its returned value. Which may be undefined because of the if statement.

Comment: @AnkushSharma well I wanted to just execute the function and return the value. I tried what you said but still undefined

Comment: @DaveNewton the function works fine when I use it in a stateless component though

Comment: Then you're doing something differently, or the data is different, etc. This is why we have console logging and debuggers if it isn't easy to figure out by looking at the code.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes it was the `if` statement thanks !!

Comment: @xxxgrime Glad you worked it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are executing the function instead of referencing.

Reference the function like so:

```
<MyContext.Provider value={{
    getOptions: this.getOptions.bind(this),
    getItem: this.state.items,
    options: this.state.options,
    removeFilter: this.removeFilter.bind(this),
    addFilter: this.addFilter.bind(this)
}}>
```

Since you use `this`, you will also need to bind it like my example.

Comment: sorry for the misleading title but I actually just wanted to execute the function in the context return the value